# Heroku Deployment of Spring Boot App from Circle CI failed

Tags: docker, heroku

I'm trying to deploy the Spring boot app through Circle CI pipeline in Heroku. Below is the error I'm getting. I couldn't figure out the root cause. Please help to resolve.

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
set -x
sudo curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
HEROKU_API_KEY=${HEROKU_API_KEY} heroku container:login
HEROKU_API_KEY=${HEROKU_API_KEY} heroku container:push -a menustage web
HEROKU_API_KEY=${HEROKU_API_KEY} heroku container:release -a menustage web
+ sudo curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh
+ sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1894  100  1894    0     0  55705      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 55705
This script requires superuser access.
You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
Installing CLI from https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-linux-x64.tar.xz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 27.2M  100 27.2M    0     0  8255k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:-- 8255k
v14.19.0
heroku installed to /usr/local/bin/heroku
 ›   Warning: HEROKU_API_KEY set to [REDACTED]
 ›   Warning: Our terms of service have changed: 
 ›   https://dashboard.heroku.com/terms-of-service
heroku/7.62.0 linux-x64 node-v14.19.0
+ HEROKU_API_KEY=************************************
+ heroku container:login
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/circleci/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
+ HEROKU_API_KEY=************************************
+ heroku container:push -a menustage web
 ▸    No images to push


Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```